# GWT designer doesn't work with Maven-GWT project

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, gwt-designer

I just started a GWT project with environment:

- Eclipse Helios
- google plugin for Eclipse 3.6
- maven2 plugin for eclipse
- Gwt designer for eclipse 3.6

The project is created by gwt-maven-plugin. The project can run in dev mode. But GWT Designer doesn't work for client GUI class. I removed Maven dependencies for GWT and directly import Eclipse GWT SDK, GWT Designer starts working for client GUI class. But it still doesn't work for UiBuilder template file.

The error message is :
UIBinder template should be in client package.

You are attempting to use UiBinder for /hsp-web/src/main/java/com/hs/hspweb/client/ui/UserListViewImpl.ui.xml, however it is not in GWT client package.

Answer (score 11):

Go to "Java build path" in project properties, click on 
"YourProjectName/src/main/resources" -> "Excluded: **" 
entry and press "Remove" button. It should change to "Excluded: (None)"
Then, you will be able to open GWT designer.

Comment: Also make sure that all files are included in "Included" entry.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here.
http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/eclipse/google_plugin.html

A restriction of this plugin is that it will search for gwt modules and host pages only in the first classpath source folder. Using a Maven / Eclipse integration like m2eclipse, this one will be your sourceDirectory (src/main/java). You'll have to move your gwt.xml files in this folder, instead of the standard Maven resource directory. See [Google Eclipse Plugin issue #1597](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1597).