# Eclipse and GWT desing mode

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am Working with GWT and eclipse. I am facing a problem . The design mode of eclipse is not working. I am using the eclipse 3.7 . Where is the problem?

Comment: Make sure that you have installed plugin in eclipse

Comment: What the mean by not working? Are you not able to install it? or After installation you are facing some error, please explain in datail

Answer (score 0):

One way to see design view is extending the view part. you can try this one.

```
public class test extends ViewPart {

    public test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }    
    @Override
    public void setFocus() {            

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click the file you want to open, then click open with --> GWT Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your resource exclusion filters are not too strict.

If you are using Maven, the issue is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518707/gwt-designer-doesnt-work-with-maven-gwt-project).